# CorePlot CPU issues. Adding data to graph in real time

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm following the examples in CorePlot to add new points to a scatter plot as I acquire them. I modeled my graph from the RealTimePlot example that ships with CoreData. I noticed that when I'm running my graphs, the CPU pegs to 100% once the screen starts scrolling to render the new data. I've tried different ways of adding the data into my dataSource as well as update calls, but I can't get anything that's both responsive and an acceptable CPU load.

After much trial and error, I fired up the RealTimePlot example to see what the CPU load was, and it's pegging at 100% as well. This is on an iPhone 5s, so I'm scared to see how a 4 will act. My question; Is there an alternative way to update the graph?

Anyhow, here is my update loop. I'm taking accelerometer data and graphing it.

```
-(void)motionController:(VWWMotionController*)sender didUpdateAcceleremeters:(CMAccelerometerData*)accelerometers{
    static NSInteger counter = 0;

    CPTGraph *theGraph = self.graph;
    CPTPlot *thePlot   = [theGraph plotWithIdentifier:@"Blue Plot"];

    if ( thePlot ) {

        if ( self.dataForPlot.count >= NUM_POINTS ) {
            [self.dataForPlot removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            [thePlot deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        }

        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)theGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
        NSUInteger location       = (counter >= NUM_POINTS ? counter - NUM_POINTS + 2 : 0);

        CPTPlotRange *oldRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger( (location > 0) ? (location - 1) : 0 )
                                                              length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(NUM_POINTS - 2)];
        CPTPlotRange *newRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(location)
                                                              length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(NUM_POINTS - 2)];

        [CPTAnimation animate:plotSpace
                     property:@"xRange"
                fromPlotRange:oldRange
                  toPlotRange:newRange
                     duration:CPTFloat(0)];


        NSNumber *x = @(counter);
        NSNumber *y = @(accelerometers.acceleration.x);
        [self.dataForPlot addObject:@{ @"x": x,
                                       @"y": y }];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [thePlot insertDataAtIndex:self.dataForPlot.count - 1 numberOfRecords:1];
        });


        counter++;
    }
}
```

FYI. I'd ideally like to have 30 FPS. I have adjusted the accelerometer callback from 1/5 to 1/30 with some CPU improvement, but then I'm loosing frame rate.

If I comment out the insertDataAtIndex line, the CPU hangs back at 1%, but of course the graph won't follow the new data. 
I don't see any derivatives of the insert method.

I've also read in other threads that recalculating the axis labels is resource intesive. I've tried removing them with very little improvement.

I'm thinking of going to OpenGL or CoreGraphics for this job.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Why animate the range with a duration of zero (0)? Just set the `xRange` directly (on the main thread) and be done with it. If you want a smooth transition from one point to the next, use a duration of 1/(frame rate).

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** I've not tested on an iPhone 5s (I've done iPhone 4s, 5, iPad 3, iPad 4, iPad Mini 1) and our apps seem to have different requirements, so I'm not positive this will help you.

Regardless, in my testing I've found that I get the best, most responsive results by redrawing all points each time I get a new data point.  This is best for me because I am having to update the graph ~120 times per second.  I don't have an iPhone around to test our app's CPU, but on an iPad Mini, the CPU is < 50% with the graph running 2 plots (~125 points each, though this fairly responsive put to around 250 points each).  The graph only has labels on the y-axis and they don't change.  The x-axis is time, and the labels are unnecessary for us.

Our requirements may be too different for this implementation to help you, but it may be worth a shot.  If you want to, it goes something like this:

```
-(void)UpdateGraph
{
    //foreach scatterplot
    {
        //Remove point from array
        //[linePlot deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(0, [array count])]
    }
    //Insert new data point into array(s)

    //foreach scatterplot
    {
        //[linePlot insertDataAtIndex:0 numberOfRecords:[array count]]
    }
    //Schedule next update if necessary
    //[self performSelector:@selector(UpdateGraph) withObject:nil afterDelay:(1/(CGFloat)Your_FPS_Here)];
}
```

Hope that helps you and best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The key is to make the graph simple and fast to draw. Set the labeling policy so that you don't have too many labels. Don't use minor ticks or grid lines (set the line styles to `nil`). Turn off major grid lines, too, if you don't need them. Don't use an area fill on the plot.